# Configure ALSA to work with [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP, [AMD] FCH Azalia

Tags: audio, gentoo, alsa, funtoo

I use Funtoo Linux + LXDE + ALSA on laptop Asus X552E. I have speaker and headphones, installed alsa, users in group audio. But sound does not appear, and I have no sense how to configure it.

Here it is my system:

```
# id -Gn
root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel floppy audio tape video 

# lspci -vnn | grep -A 1 -i audio
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1043:148d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
--
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH Azalia Controller [1043:148d]


# cat /usr/src/linux/.config--2017-10-10--11-27-24.bak | nc termbin.com 9999
http://termbin.com/ps6n

# ./alsa-info.sh
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e4bd36bf84c38e87c9e699ddce5f87f5f8d4daae
```

This is alsamixer screen and installed ebuilds `equery l *alsa*` https://postimg.org/image/qqh6se87t/

How to configure driver?

Answer (score 3):

solved with this http://icomputo.com/SinsonidoconALSAAMDFCHAzaliaControllerrev02Solucion

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/50-alsa.conf
options snd-hda-intel index=1,0

$ reboot
```

Comment: That worked for me when installing Arch Linux on a Lenovo G505 laptop which has the same audio hardware.  No sound at all without those modue options.   I disagree with the 'off topic' opinion.

Comment: Worked on Lubuntu 18.04 on HP 655.

Comment: `cat` doesn't change the system. Are you suggesting that a solution is to create/edit `/etc/modprobe.d/50-alsa.conf` to make it contain only `options snd-hda-intel index=1,0`?